# Ubuntu 16.04 Mouse flickering while hovering window border

Tags: 16.04, mouse, mouse-pointer

I am new to Ubuntu and I discovered a problem while using it. When I move my mouse to the top border of a window, example on the web browser, where the tabs are, my mouse instantly starts to flicker.

This makes it hard to close windows because of the mouse lag. Is there any solutions or ideas on this problem? Thank you :)

Graphics info:

*-display

```
   description: VGA compatible controller

   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics
```

Controller

```
   vendor: Intel Corporation

   physical id: 2

   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0

   version: 09

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz

   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom

   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

   resources: irq:36 memory:dc400000-dc7fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Do you mean flicker visually in one place or jump around in position?  And does this only happen near the top border of windows, not other places? Is it related to being at the top of the screen?

Comment: It might help to post details of your graphics card and what graphics driver you have. Comment if you need help doing that! Also, is this a direct installation not a virtual machine?

Comment: It flickers visually in one place, and it happens while you are outside the main window in a program, it even flickers at the sidebar in the desktop. Otherwise, it flickers at the top of programs, so when I use the Ubuntu Software, it will flicker when I move my mouse to the top widget thing. I will look up the graphics, one sec

Comment: If the pointer position is stable, it's probably just an issue with the pointer icon that's being displayed. As in all/most window managers, this changes depending on what the mouse is over. Does it make a difference if you change the theme?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For some reason I had a dual screen that I noticed when I went to the **Workspace Switcher**. So I went to **System Settings**, then to **Displays** and I turned the other display off which was called **Unknown Display**. This left me with **Built-in Display** after I applied the changes by hitting the **Apply** button.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was my Nvidia graphics driver problem. I disabled the GPU from
**Nvidia X server settings → PRIME Profiles → *Select* Intel**

Then re-login on your account, I observed that the mouse flickering goes away. I again switched to my NVidia GPU (there was no flickering anymore).

[image]